# Helping friends pay for a party

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, gift-tax, gifts

We're throwing a BIG party next year. Our friends have agreed to contribute.

The total cost of the party comes to £20,000. Our friends will contribute £15,000 and we will subsidise the rest.

This is not a business venture and we will not be making a profit.

As large amounts of money is being dealt with, do we need to set up a business? Is there a way that this can be "gifted"?

As I run a business separate to this, should I inform HMRC?

Comment: The real question is, how does one receive an invitation to said party?

Comment: @BobbyScon Ha ha, I knew that one was coming!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There’s no need to set up a business for this. Gifts between friends are, to a first approximation, tax free; the only thing would be that if your friends then died within 7 years the gift would form part of their estate (tapered over the 7 years) for inheritance tax purposes. All the info about this side of things is covered [here](https://www.gov.uk/inheritance-tax/gifts).